# Java: Change value of static variable by class name string

Tags: java, class, static-variables

I have the following structure for a big Java project:

```
Class BigParentClass
{
...
};
```

And then many classes that extend this BigParentClass, all of which have an the same static variable.

```
Class A extends BigParentClass 
{
    static boolean importantVal = false;
};

Class B extends BigParentClass
{
    static boolean importantVal = false;
}
..etc..
```

What I need to do is, during initialization, I will get a list of class name strings in which I need to set the static variable importantVal to TRUE. So I will get a list such as:

"A, C, F, K"

and I need a manner in which to change the static variable for classes A, C, F, K to TRUE. What would be the way to do this?

I have tried doing something like:

```
Class strToClass = Class.forName(classNameString);
```

However, there is no way to reference the "importantVal" static variable without casting that Class variable to an actual class that has it. Do I need to just cut my losses, and have a switch statement for all of my classes that makes the change I need:

```
Class class = Class.forName(classNameString);
switch(class)
{
    case A:
        (A)class.importantVal = true;
        break;
    case B:
        (B)class.importantVal = true;
        break;
    ..etc..
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something very weird. Why do you want to change the variable? What's the big picture?

Comment: I need to render something differently based on this value, and this value can be changed by an external source (I would be getting a file with the class names who require this to be changed). The only other option would be to, when doing the actual rendering, compare the current class with this list, but this is potentially a large list and the render and re-rendering occurs quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `getDeclaredField` method and `set` on the class object itself, since it's a static field.

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("MyClass");
clazz.getDeclaredField("importantVal").set(null, true);
```

So, within your iteration:

```
for (String fullyQualifiedClassName: myIterable) {
    try {
        Class
            .forName(fullyQualifiedClassName)
            .getDeclaredField("importantVal").set(null, true);
    }
    // java 7 idiom here to simplify
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | 
           IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO handle
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `set(null, true)`?

Comment: ["If the underlying field is static, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) So, yeah, either work. I prefer the null, since it looks like you're setting a field on the `Class` instance otherwise.

Comment: Was about to comment with the same quote :) But agreed, the `null` idiom is better.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a bad design.  Instead of setting other classes’ fields, let each class set its own value by pulling in the initial configuration:

```
public class InitialConfig {
    public static Collection<String> importantValueEnabledClassNames() {
        // Read class name strings here
    }
}

public class A extends BigParentClass {
    static final boolean importantVal =
        InitialConfig.importantValueEnabledClassNames().contains(
            A.class.getName());
}

public class B extends BigParentClass {
    static final boolean importantVal =
        InitialConfig.importantValueEnabledClassNames().contains(
            B.class.getName());
}
```